Solana wallet adapter integration in next js
Can anyone help me with Solana wallet adapter integration with nextjs? I'm facing some issues. If anyone can share latest example for the same?

You can look up this documentation from solana Add Solana Wallet Adapter to a NextJS application
and you can also take a look at this repo Create an application that lets a user connect their wallet and send SOL to another account
and lastly you can try posting the issues you are having.
